# Does a universal homeomorphism descend ampleness?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

All schemes are quasicompact and separated. If $\pi:X\to Y$ is an affine morphism and $L$ is an ample invertible $\mathscr{O}_Y$-module, then $\pi^*L$ is ample on $X$; we say that $\pi$ *descends ampleness* if the converse holds (for any $L$).

**Some context.**  We denote by $\pi:X\to Y$ an integral and surjective morphism.

- To show that $\pi$ descends ampleness, we may assume that $X$ and $Y$ are reduced because $L$ is ample on $Y$ iff its restriction to $Y_\mathrm{red}$ is. (This is not completely trivial. For  the noetherian case see EGA II, 4.5.13  or [Tag 09MS](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09MS); in general, see [Tag 09MW](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09MW)).
- We may also assume that $\pi$ is finite by a standard limit argument.
- Here are two useful cases where $\pi$ descends ampleness: when $\pi$ is locally free (equivalently, flat of finite presentation), and when $Y$ is noetherian and normal. In both cases, this is because we have a good notion of "norm" $N_{X/Y}L$ for invertible $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules $L$, see EGA II, sections 6.5 and 6.6.
- Another useful case is when $Y$ (and hence $X$) is proper over an affine noetherian scheme $S$, see [Tag 0B5V](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B5V). A combination of this and the previous cases is given in EGA III, 2.6.2.
- A nice example where $\pi$ does not descend ampleness is given in [Tag 0271](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0271). In this example, $L$ is $\mathscr{O}_X$: in other words, $X$ is quasi-affine but $Y$ is not. Specifically, $X$ is the punctured affine plane $\mathbb{A}^2_k\smallsetminus\{(0,0)\}$ over a field $k$, and $Y$ is obtained by identifying the two (punctured) axes via $(x,0)\mapsto(0,x^{-1})$.

> **Question.** Let $\pi:X\to Y$ be a universal homeomorphism (in particular, $\pi$ is  integral). Does $\pi$ descend ampleness?

The question has a positive answer if $Y$ is noetherian of characteristic $p>0$. Indeed, assuming $\pi$ finite and $X$, $Y$ reduced, there is an  $m>0$ such that the $m$-iterated absolute Frobenius $\Phi_Y^m:Y\to Y$ factors through $\pi$. (See for instance Proposition 35 in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.3608v2), where the assumption that $S$ is essentially of finite type over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is not needed). So if $\pi^*L$ is ample, so is $(\Phi_Y^m)^*L$ which is isomorphic to $L^{\otimes p^m}$.

Comment: I wrote an incomplete argument earlier, but that argument does give that $Y$ is quasicompact and separated, hence a limit of finite type $\mathbb{Z}$-schemes with affine transition maps.  If also $\pi$ is finitely presented, this gives the result.

Comment: Jason, just settling the noetherian case would be great!

Comment: I guess I spoke too soon.  I thought we had a "Chevalley type" theorem (ampleness descends through finite, finitely presented morphisms) in the quasi-projective case.